# How to flip half of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, flip

I have a numpy array:

```
arr=np.array([[1., 2., 0.],
               [2., 4., 1.],
               [1., 3., 2.],
               [-1., -2., 4.],
               [-1., -2., 5.],
               [1., 2., 6.]])
```

I want to flip the second half of this array upward. I mean I want to have:

```
flipped_arr=np.array([[-1., -2., 4.],
                      [-1., -2., 5.],
                      [1., 2., 6.],
                      [1., 2., 0.],
                      [2., 4., 1.],
                      [1., 3., 2.]])
```

When I try this code:

```
fliped_arr=np.flip(arr, 0)
```

It gives me:

```
fliped_arr= array([[1., 2., 6.],
                   [-1., -2., 5.],
                   [-1., -2., 4.],
                   [1., 3., 2.],
                   [2., 4., 1.],
                   [1., 2., 0.]])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when the number of rows in the array is odd?

Comment: @Kalpit, Thanks for your hint. Then I want to say from that line until the end, bring rows with the same order up. Then that nth line will be the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply concatenate rows below the `n`th row (included) with [np.r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for instance, with row index `n` of your choice, at the top and the other ones at the bottom:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3

arr_flip_n = np.r_[arr[n:],arr[:n]]

>>> array([[-1., -2.,  4.],
           [-1., -2.,  5.],
           [ 1.,  2.,  6.],
           [ 1.,  2.,  0.],
           [ 2.,  4.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  3.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by slicing the array using the midpoint:

```
ans = np.vstack((arr[int(arr.shape[0]/2):], arr[:int(arr.shape[0]/2)]))
```

to break this down a little:

find the midpoint of arr, by finding its shape, the first index of which is the number of rows, dividing by two and converting to an integer:

```
midpoint = int(arr.shape[0]/2)
```

the two halves of the array can then be sliced like so:

```
a = arr[:midpoint]
b = arr[midpoint:]
```

then stack them back together using `np.vstack`:

```
ans = np.vstack((a, b))
```

(note vstack takes a single argument, which is a tuple containing a and b: `(a, b)`)

Comment: Hi @Finley, how is this different than my answer?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be. Your's wasn't there at the time of posting. (appeared upon the refresh that came with posting the asnwer)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with array slicing and vstack -

```
arr=np.array([[1., 2., 0.],
               [2., 4., 1.],
               [1., 3., 2.],
               [-1., -2., 4.],
               [-1., -2., 5.],
               [1., 2., 6.]])

mid = arr.shape[0]//2  
np.vstack([arr[mid:],arr[:mid]])
```

```
array([[-1., -2.,  4.],
       [-1., -2.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.]])
```